# remove stale files from Amazon S3 before uploading

Tags: django, amazon-s3

In a django project need to upload static data to amazon S3, a bit searching finds out that [django-storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) and `collectstatic` management command can help me out there.

My use-case is the front-end will generate the complied static files (js, css). And those files need to be uploaded to S3.

unused file should be removed from s3 before uploading changed files.

Suppose **index.js** created a compiled file `index_11.js`, which already present on S3, after `index.js` file is changed and compiled file `index_22.js` should be uploaded and `index_11.js` should be removed from S3.

Is is possible through the **collectstatic** or otherwise?